# Set environment variable and run node.js server

Tags: freebsd, node.js

In Ubuntu I have this:

```
$ DEBUG=* node server.js
```

But in FreeBSD I try this and got the following error:

```
# setenv DEBUG * node server.js
setenv: Too many arguments.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: which error you are getting. Please modify your question accordingly by editing.

Comment: i edited the question and add the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are confusing `setenv` with [`env`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=env). The `setenv` builtin in [`csh`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=csh&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+10.0-RELEASE) and [`sh`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+10.0-RELEASE) is only used to define the value of environment variables, it does not take a command to be executed like `env` does.

Typical usage for `setenv` is:

```
setenv [VAR [word]]
```

while typical usage for `env` is:

```
env [VAR=word ...] [command [argument ...]]
```

for instance:

```
env DEBUG="*" node server.js
```

Comment: yes, you'r right. but please help me do such a thing that i do in ubuntu :)

Comment: @Mosayeb Updated the answer with example usage of `env`.

Comment: I still got this error: `env: No match.`

Comment: I should use this: `env DEBUG="*" node server.js`. thanks :)